# Problem with adding inside of if loop inside of a function in Java

Tags: java, function, addition

I've been trying to get this by myself for hours but I'm new to coding, so I don't really know how to fix this. When I call the cost again, it won't add the number I try to add and won't budge off of 0. I want the "cost" integer to add 1 to itself when the user inputs the word "Small".

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide full code as we can not see where the function is called

Comment: You are missing pranthesis for the function

Comment: made an edit guys, sorry if it wasn't too clear

Comment: @washeddaniel, the `cost` inside the method hides the `cost` variable decalred outside. So `cost = cost + 1` only impacts the method parameter `cost`

Comment: return cost from the method and reassign it. To understand this, read whats `pass by reference` & whats `pass by value`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/7804477

Comment: @washeddaniel you have mentioned "loop" in the question title, but i don't see any loops in your code.

Comment: @GauthamM and all you guys are the best I fixed it

Comment: Please undo your last edit. The question makes no sense now, and the answer you get also makes no sense because you removed your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing the cost to the function as a parameter, which for primitives (like`int` or `float`) means that what you're working with inside the function is not the `cost` variable declared outside the function, but merely a copy with the same value. So when you increment the variable, you're actually incrementing the copy that was passed into the function.

The fix should be quite simple: just remove the `cost` parameter and you'll automatically be working with the global variable instead.

Also, it seems weird that you're calling a function (presumably) directly inside the class body which should normally give a compiler error.